# Fatal error: Index out of range for in loops swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, pdf, for-loop

Im trying to create a save to pdf method using the simplePDF framework on Github. I have several arrays and have tried to use a for in loop. Its my first go at this, but I do not understand why I am getting fatal error: Index out of range. Here is my code.

```
let A4paperSize = CGSize(width: 595, height: 842)
    let pdf = SimplePDF(pageSize: A4paperSize)
    pdf.setContentAlignment(.center)

    let count = Globals.datesArray.count
    var sum = 0

    for index in 0...count {
        pdf.addText(Globals.datesArray[index])
        pdf.addText(Globals.titleArray[index])
        pdf.addText(Globals.descriptionArray[index])
        sum += index
    }

    let pdfData = pdf.generatePDFdata()
```

Any help  is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Change condition of for loop to 
   `for index in 0 ..< count`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both answers are correct, but neither are ideal.

This would work:

```
for index in 0..<count {
```

However, it's much better to use:

```
for index in Globals.datesArray.indicies
```

This way the range is created for you, and removes the potential for a typo (`...` instead of `..<`)

### On a side note:

What concerns me is your use of 3 arrays to store related data. Wikipedia has a section on the [pros and cons of parallel arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array#Pros_and_cons). They really have no place in modern, high-level programming. They're cumbersome to work with, and very fragile. For example, if you add an element to the middle of
`datesArray` and `titleArray`, but forget to add a description in `descriptionArray`, all of a sudden, you have mismatching between your dates/titles and descriptions.

You should try using a [`class` or `struct`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html). For example, you might want a struct declaration like this:

```
struct Thing { //TODO: give me a name!
    let date: Date
    let title: String
    let description: String
}
```

This lets you change a messy parallel structure like this:

```
let datesArray = [date0, date1, date2]
let titlesArray = ["title0", "title1", "title2"]
let descriptionsArray = ["Description 0", "Description 1", "Description 2"]
```

Into one like this:

```
let things = [
    Thing(
        date: date0,
        title: "title0"
        description: "Description 0"
    ),
    Thing(
        date: date1,
        title: "title1"
        description: "Description 1"
    ),
    Thing(
        date: date2,
        title: "title2"
        description: "Description 2"
    ),
]
```

With this second declaration, all the information pertaining to a single `Thing` is stored cohesively. It lets you much more easily make additions/edits. No more counting elements to make sure they're lined up!

With such a struct in place, your code can be written like this:

```
let A4paperSize = CGSize(width: 595, height: 842)
let pdf = SimplePDF(pageSize: A4paperSize)
pdf.setContentAlignment(.center)

var sum = 0

for (index, thing) in things.enumerated() {
    pdf.addText(thing.date)
    pdf.addText(thing.title)
    pdf.addText(thing.description)
    sum += index
}

let pdfData = pdf.generatePDFdata()
```

That snippet uses [`enumerated()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1687832-enumerated), which lets you iterate over elements and their index. This way, we don't have to subscript our array in the loop body.

However, the `sum` in this case will always be the sum of [`0, 1, ... , count`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF). This is equal to just `(count * (count + 1)) / 2`, so we can simplify the code further:

```
let A4paperSize = CGSize(width: 595, height: 842)
let pdf = SimplePDF(pageSize: A4paperSize)
pdf.setContentAlignment(.center)

for (index, thing) in things.enumerated() {
    pdf.addText(thing.date)
    pdf.addText(thing.title)
    pdf.addText(thing.description)
}

let pdfData = pdf.generatePDFdata()

let sum = (count * (count + 1)) / 2
```

Now since we're not using `index` in the `for` loop body anymore, we can use regular iteration, without `enumerated()`:

```
let A4paperSize = CGSize(width: 595, height: 842)
let pdf = SimplePDF(pageSize: A4paperSize)
pdf.setContentAlignment(.center)

for index in things {
    pdf.addText(thing.date)
    pdf.addText(thing.title)
    pdf.addText(thing.description)
}

let pdfData = pdf.generatePDFdata()

let sum = (count * (count + 1)) / 2
```

Comment: This the best answer here.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to David's answer:

```
for index in 0...count {
```

could be

```
for index in 0..<count {
```

This will loop up until but not including count.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, This also works. If I could accept two answers, I would accept yours too.

Comment: Just except whichever one you think is better. Either way works just as well so doesn't matter to me which you accept.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be `let count = Globals.datesArray.count - 1`. If Globals.count == 3, then index are [0,1,2], [3] would be out of range.

Comment: This answer is not as good as [WMios's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40120354/fatal-error-index-out-of-range-for-in-loops-swift-3/40120423#40120423) since putting `Array.count - 1` into a variable called `count` is more misleading and less readable.

Comment: I was just explaining where the error "out of range" comes from. The best solution is "for myVar in Globals.datesArray { }"